# Чтение сырого сокета от сервера в программе на Qt

Tags: qt, c++, сеть

Хочу заюзать Qt для написания небольшого софта для расширения услуг сайта, но какого либо значимого опыта программирования сетей на сях не имею. Взялся изучать Qt для облегчения жизни и кроссплатформенности.
Имеется TCP сервер на Node (упрощенный вариант).

```
var net = require('net');
net.createServer(function(s) {
  s.write('Hello');
});
```

Вот пример взятый из книги по Qt, переделал для отправки сырых данных (изначально классы):

```
QByteArray arrBlock;
QDataStream out(&arrBlock, QIODevice::WriteOnly);
out.setVersion(QDataStream::Qt_5_2);

QByteArray arr(m_txtInput->text().toUtf8());
out.writeRawData(arr, arr.size());

m_tcpSocket->write(arrBlock);
m_txtInput->clear();
```

Все прекрасно работает, строка берется из QLineEdit.

Код для принятия данных в виде классов:

```
QTcpSocket* clientSocket = (QTcpSocket*)sender();
QDataStream in(clientSocket);
in.setVersion(QDataStream::Qt_5_2);
while (true) {
    if (!m_nextBlockSize) {
        if (clientSocket->bytesAvailable() < sizeof(quint16)) {
            break;
        }
        in >> m_nextBlockSize;
    }
    if (clientSocket->bytesAvailable() < m_nextBlockSize) {
        break;
    }

    ///!!!

    QTime time;
    QString str;
    in >> time >> str;

    // Обработка и вывод.
    m_nextBlockSize = 0;
}
```

Пробовал переделать по аналоги, но данные не приходят, и вообще, выполнение программы не доходит до отметки "//!!!". В общем, как правильно читать сырые данные в Qt?

Comment: @Denis Neustroev, подозреваю, что на самом деле речь идет о сокетах типа SOCK_STREAM, а не SOCK_RAW (Обеспечивает доступ к низкоуровневому сетевому протоколу. Именно их принято называть "сырыми").

Comment: @avp, спасибо, буду знать, как говорил, опыта в этой сфере мало) думаю, в скором времени разберусь в терминологии и программированием сетей в целом.

Comment: Если не секрет - скажите из какой книги взяли пример приведенный в вопросе?

Comment: @dreadangel, не секрет - "Шлее М. - Qt 4.8. Профессиональное программирование на C++"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

могу поделится парой кусков живого кода, где работают Qt сокеты, правда не на плюсах, а на питоне, но смысл остается не изменным.
[клиентская часть](https://github.com/alexandr-nino/rtsGame/blob/master/client/network.py)
[серверная часть](https://github.com/alexandr-nino/rtsGame/blob/master/server/main.py)
в целом все сводится к простым действиям над QTcpSocket (async версия):
инитиализировать QTcpSocket с ссылкой на родителя который прямо или косвенно наследуется от QThread (QWidget в полне подходит), это надо для того чтобы работали асинхронные эвенты
получить эвент readyReady, произвести чтение из сокета и сформировать ответ по необходимости...

Comment: большое вам спасибо) с разбором кода на питоне сложностей не возникло, с языком хорошо знаком) сделал по аналогии, но, однако в коде считывал размер так: in >> nSize; а потом еще код m_tcpSocket.size() получалось так, что у данных не хватало 2 байт, не знал, что in >> nSize помечает данные как прочитанные) удалил и все заработало) еще раз спасибо)

Comment: да, хоть сокеты часто и сравнивают с файлами, но чтение из сокета всегда затирает прочитанные данные т.к это все таки поток данных, которые либо еще непрочитаны либо уже несуществует... в отличии от файлов где одни и те же данные можно читать сколько угодно раз.
P.S: благодарности отмечаются принятием ответа)

Comment: сделал глупую ошибку, с сервер предварительно не посылал размер данных, как в десктопной версии, но код для считывания размера оставил яа он как раз и "съедал" те два байта. Естественно отмечу) после того, как выбираешь правильный ответ, отключаются комментарии, но а вдруг еще что полезного напишут, вот и оставляю это дело на следующий день)

Comment: @Denis Neustroev, когда программируют сокеты на "низком уровне", то для чтения используется функция

     int recv(int sock, void *buf, size_t len, int flags); 

и в `flags` можно установить

     MSG_PEEK

    Этот флаг заставляет выбрать данные из начала очереди, но не удалять их оттуда. Таким образом, последующий вызов функции вернет те же самые данные.

Если подобное чтение Вам потребуется, то, думаю в QT есть тоже средства управления `flags`.